# Active Admin: can't scope the resource to current_admin_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, activeadmin

There is only admin interface in my app and I use AdminUser model. The admin users can have different roles.

I want to change the resource retrieval based on admin role. I added to my ActiveAdmin register block:

```
#app/admin/payments.rb
scope_to :current_admin_user
```

And I expect I could write something like:

```
#app/models/admin_user.rb
def payments
  case self.role
  when role == 'manager'
    Payments.where('...')
  when role == '...'
  end
end
```

But this doesn't work and always shows all the resources.

Any idea how can I get this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the better solution, then.

Authorization adapter do just fine, and there is not need for scopes. For example, with CanCan:

```
class Ability
include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)

    #read/manage actions
    if user.role == 'manager'
      can :manage, Payment, :accessible_by_manager => true

    elsif user.role == 'accountant'
      can :read, Payment, :accessible_by_accountant => true
    else
      #can read all
      can :read, Payment
    end    
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I used the scoped_collection method

```
ActiveAdmin.register Payment do

 ...

 controller do

  def scoped_collection
    #roles which need to be scoped  
    if current_admin_user.role == 'accountant' or current_admin_user.role == 'manager'
        resource_class.send(current_admin_user.role)
    end
 end
end
```

And then just define the scopes in the model:

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope 'accountant', where('...')
  scope 'manager', where('...')

 ...
 end
```